Cannot insert the mapsto character ↦ in groff
I am trying to learn how to insert the mapsto (↦, U+21A6) character in groff.
I am trying to use this code to insert the character
\[u21A6]

But I get the following error message and nothing is inserted in the output file:
troff: doc.ms:40: warning: can't find special character 'u21A6'

I have tried to follow multiple tutorials and read some documentation, but could not find a solution to the problem.
What am I doing wrong?
(by the way I tried with and without the -Kutf8 option, as well as inserting the Unicode character ↦ as is in the file)
Here is a document example (file test.ms):
.TL
document
.LP
a \[u02DA] b

a ↦ b

.EQ
define maps_to % ↦ %
a maps_to b
.EN

And the command line I use is:
groff -e -ms -Kutf8 test.ms | gv -


Can you post the smallest document that contains the required translation as well as a few characters that should be unchanged AND the exact text of the groff cmd-line you are using. Readers prefer to copy/paste into their own environment for experimenting.

@shellter I added it to the question.

I explained how to do this for another character in another answer. In addition, using eqn and the ms macros add further complications, as the font needs to be specified for each.
For ms you need to have a font family of 4 fonts. You need to repeat the conversion of the ttf font to PostScript Type 1 format for the 4 fonts in a family, not just DejaVuSans-Bold. For example, use the bash script
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p /tmp/font/devps
cd  /tmp/font/devps
(
  convert(){ 
    from=${1?} to=${2?}
    echo " $to"
    ttf2pt1 -a -e "$1" "$2"
    afmtodit "$2".afm textmap "$2"
  }

  dir=dejavu-sans-fonts
  convert /usr/share/fonts/$dir/DejaVuSans.ttf DejaVuSansR
  convert /usr/share/fonts/$dir/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf DejaVuSansB
  convert /usr/share/fonts/$dir/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf DejaVuSansI
  convert /usr/share/fonts/$dir/DejaVuSans-BoldOblique.ttf DejaVuSansBI
) 2>errors

You may need to change dir= to the appropriate name used by your distribution.
Then add to the start of your document the troff command
.ds FAM DejaVuSans

Before running groff and gv, remember to
export GROFF_FONT_PATH=/tmp/font
export GS_FONTPATH=/tmp/font

I'm not too familiar with fonts in eqn, but you would need something like
.EQ
grfont DejaVuSansR
...



Thanks a lot it worked! But on my system I had to use ttf2ufm instead of ttf2pt1 (it was not available). Which should work almost identically.
